# Dissimilarity and distance based clustering around outliers using R?

Tags: r, clustering

I have point data for healthcare facilities for a country - I want to first identify outlier facilities (that serve most no of patients) and then cluster nearby facilities that serve lower than average patients. The idea is that for every facility I have no. of patients that tested HIV positive and were subsequently put on ART treatment. I have created a variable Treatment gap = patients that test HIV Positive -  patients put on ART. I want to cluster facilities that have high Treatment gap with facilities that have low Treatment gap in a radius of 50 kms. Idea is to see if patients are being served on clinics other than the one they were tested at. I have some additional features at the facility level i.e. is it urban/rural, clinic/teaching hospital etc. I am trying to do this in R and am new to GIS. Any pointers for what type of analysis/package I can use would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Could you update with what you have tried or any example code? Please read the tour https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: This is a very broad problem asking all sorts of questions. This isn't really the platform for giving pointers to your analysis methods, its really for focused questions and correct answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are invariably describing a multivariate model and an intent to draw inference from the results, I would highly recommend perusing a spatial regression approach. A simple cluster analysis is going to be of limited use and could actually be misleading. I would first, define a testable hypothesis and then start exploring your data's autocorrelation/autocovariance structure (eg., structure of the residual error in an OLS using something like the Lagrange diagnostic, if a continuous response the global autocorrelation, etc...) and how a given spatial process is supporting your hypothesis.

If a spatial approach is supported, you could then start exploring methods along the lines of a spatial lag or spatial error model. These types of models can be specified using the `lagsarlm` or `errorsarlm` functions in the R spdep package. I would encourage you to dig into the literature on spatial regression approaches to understand the correct specification. Please stay away from GWR approaches as, they seem appealing at first blush but are quite suspect and are not appropriate unless nonstationarity is readily apparent in the data.

If your hypothesis and data supports the evaluation of a point clustering process, you could look into Kulldorff scan statistics (Kulldorff 1997) as you can define distributional assumptions to support a given hypothesis. There is a fairly large body of literature on this type of analysis and a fairly robust implementation in the software [SaTScan](https://www.satscan.org/) or the R package [rsatscan](https://www.satscan.org/rsatscan/rsatscan.html). This type of statistic is particularly well suited for spatial-temporal problems as well. You can also expand scan statistics into a multivariate case. More recent advances of the statistic support a Bernoulli process thus, expanding the model to support hypothesis following binomial distributions, which may support your question regarding treatment gaps.

Kulldorff M.A., (1997) Spatial scan statistic. Communications in Statistics: Theory and Methods, 26:1481-1496.

Comment: Thanks @JeffreyEvans. This seems more appropriate than the answer I had posted.

Comment: @JeffereyEvans Thanks a lot - this was very useful!